# how to force accept only ssl connections in vsftpd?

Tags: linux, ssl, ftp, vsftpd

I did install and configure `vsftpd` with ssl using openssl.
But I want to accept only ssl connections, or, in other words, deny non-ssl connections.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If you set "force_local_logins_ssl=YES" then your clients will be
>   required to use an FTP client that supports AUTH TLS/SSL in order to
>   connect. If you leave it at "NO" then people can connect securely or
>   insecurely.

[Source](http://wiki.vpslink.com/Configuring_vsftpd_for_secure_connections_%28TLS/SSL/SFTP%29)

All you need to do is change that setting in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` or in `/etc/vsftp/vsftpd.conf`; depending on your distro, the `.conf` file should be on of those 2 places. Then all you should need to do is restart `vsftpd` daemon as so:

```
vsftpd restart
```

**EDIT**

You may also need to set `ssl_enable=YES` for this to take effect (as pointed out by Tegran in the comments)

Comment: This doesn't actually help. I still can use pure FTP. Still.

Comment: force_local_logins_ssl=YES is actually the default but it does not take effect unless you also specify:

ssl_enable=YES

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the following option in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and restart the server:

```
ssl_enable=YES
```

Setting `force_local_logins_ssl=YES` is also required but it's actually the default as long as you have SSL enabled.

Beware, if you just set `force_local_logins_ssl=YES` without `ssl_enable=YES` then you will **not** be preventing people from logging on without an encrypted connection.